# Firebase realtime database query latest 10 records using timestamp key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this collection in firebase realtime database:

**students**:

```
{
  "Mike": {
    "Time 2022-08-22 09:04:57": {
      "Courses": [
        "Maths",
        "Chemistry",
        "Science"
      ]
    },
    "Time 2022-08-15 09:05:58": {
      "Courses": [
        "Physics",
        "Geography",
        "Literature"
      ]
    },
    "Time 2022-08-15 09:06:59": {
      "Courses": [
        "Computer Science",
        "Biology",
        "Chemistry"
      ]
    }
  },
  "John": {
    "Time 2022-08-22 10:04:57": {
      "Courses": [
        "Maths",
        "Chemistry",
        "Science"
      ]
    },
    "Time 2022-08-15 10:05:58": {
      "Courses": [
        "Physics",
        "Geography",
        "Literature"
      ]
    },
    "Time 2022-08-15 10:06:59": {
      "Data": [
        "Computer Science",
        "Biology",
        "Chemistry"
      ]
    },
    "Time 2022-08-15 10:07:59": {
      "Courses": [
        "Computer Science",
        "Biology",
        "Physics"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Steve": {
    "Time 2022-08-22 11:01:57": {
      "Courses": [
        "Maths",
        "Chemistry",
        "Science"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now here I want to get latest 2 courses records of a selected student.

What I tried so far is:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.2.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
var config = {};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var records = [];
var currentTimestamp = new Date().getTime();

var ref = firebase.database().ref("students/John")

ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    
    var records = snapshot.val();
    
    for(var key in records) {

        if(currentTimestamp < new Date(key.replace('Time ','')).getTime()){

            records.push({
                timestamp: key,
                arrayRecords: records[key].Courses
            });           
        }            
    }    
});
</script>
```

Now i need to achieve this by a query not using the timestamp check that I am using.

Comment: can't you change the document type to something like {time: "time value" , restOfTheData}? because you can query some fields but your key is a string which holds date data. I don't think that you can filter that field with a query.

Comment: @DenizKaradağ thats where I am stuck, I dont have permision to change structure

Answer (score 1):

To get only the two most recent courses for a student, you can do:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref("students/John")

const query = ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(2);

query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  ...
})
```

Comment: this seems to be working fine, what if I only want to fetch list of users here?

Comment: Can you also provide the reference documentation url?

Comment: How can I sort these records by ASC or DESC?

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database can only return results in ascending order. If you want to get descending order, you'll need to reverse them in your application code. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+descending